# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently, [a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98415/how-to-view-the-latest-entries-in-all-tables-in-an-oracle-db/) that I answered was voted off-topic. I would like a clarification why exactly is this off-topic?

I think the question was relevant to this site. It might not have an exact answer, but imperfect information that can be gained in this situation is better than no information at all.